# Class logical error with tester shows previous time instead of new

Tags: java

Just joined StackOverflow and hope to continue growing in this amazing community :)

I got a code that I am writing for my studies which I don't understand why the class 'setHour' and 'setMinute' work properly.

I've been playing with the code again and again and still don't get the issue.
I also have a test code which uses 'setHour' and 'setMinute' and still don't get it.

I must mention that the variables that are used in those two classes are required, and a private '_minFromMidnight' is also required, but I am allowed to add public variables.

This is the code:

```
public class Time2
{
 // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
 private int _minFromMidnight;
 int _num;
 int _h;
 int _m;
 final int minInDay = 1440; //Total minutes per day

     /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Time2
     */
  public Time2(int h, int m)
    {   _h = h;
        _m = m;

        if (_h > 23 || _h < 0)
          {   
            _h = 0;
          }
        else _minFromMidnight = _h; 

        if (_m > 59 || _m < 0)
          {
            _m = 0;
          }
        else _minFromMidnight = _m;

        _minFromMidnight = (h*60) +m;
    }

    public Time2(Time2 other)
    {
        _minFromMidnight = other._minFromMidnight;
    }
    public void setHour(int num)
    {
      if ((num >= 0) && ( num < 24))
         _h = num;
         else num = 0;
    }

    public void setMinute(int num)
    {

      if ((num >= 0) && (num < 59))
        _m = num;
      else num = 0;

    }
    public int getHour()
    {
      return _h;
    }

    public int getMinute()
    {
     return _m;
    }
}
```

the tester I have is the following:

```
    Time2 t1 = new Time2(17, 45);
    System.out.println("\tt1=" + t1);
    System.out.println("\n2. Testing accessors and mutators:");
    t1.setHour(20);
    t1.setMinute(10);
    System.out.println("\tt1=" + t1);
    System.out.println("\tHour   of t1=" + t1.getHour());
    System.out.println("\tMinute of t1=" + t1.getMinute());
```

The output shows this:

```
2. Testing accessors and mutators:
    t1=17:45
    Hour   of t1=20
    Minute of t1=10
```

I've been sitting on this case for more than 3 days and I still don't know what seems to be the issue.

Sorry if this looks messy/dumb. I'm new at this...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found my own answer :)
the problem was that the variables weren't stated correctly, therefore the logic was bad.

I just simply re-adjusted almost all of my code:

```
 public Time2(int h, int m)
    {       
        int hours; 
        int minutes;

        if (h > 23 || h < 0)
        {   
            hours = 0;
        }
        else hours = h; 

        if (m > 59 || m < 0)
        {
            minutes = 0;
        }
        else minutes = m;

        _minFromMidnight = (hours*60) + minutes;
    }
 public int getHour()
    {
        return _minFromMidnight /60;
    }

 public int getMinute()
    {
        return _minFromMidnight %60 ;
    }

 public void setHour(int num)
    {
          if (num < 0 || num > 23)
             return;
             this._minFromMidnight = getMinute() + (num * 60);
    }

 public void setMinute(int num)
    {

          if (num < 0 || num > 59)
            return;
              this._minFromMidnight = (getHour() * 60) + num;

    }
```

Used the same tester and viola!

```
2. Testing accessors and mutators:
    t1=20:10
    Hour   of t1=20
    Minute of t1=10
```

Sorry for the headache, I just had to re-run it all to get it :)

Thank you!

Comment: As a new member, I recommend that you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and after that you should visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) where you will find [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

iGraffiti.
It looks like your code has several logical inconsistencies, which probably led to your issue.
If I got you right, the issue is that output shows "t1=17:45" despite you had invoked

```
t1.setHour(20);
t1.setMinute(10);
```

before printing it.

The actual problem probably lays in incorrect implementation of toString() method for your class Time2. It seems you have it based on _minFromMidnight field, which doesn't get updated when you change Hour and Minute for Time2 instances.
To solve the problem with incorrect printing, you should change your toString() method implementation for your Time2 class, so that it looks like the following:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return _h + ":" + _m;
}
```

Unfortunately apart from this issue you could find that current implentation of Time2 class introduces several other errors, but hope you would be able to solve them in the future.